# What does the word 「いつの間に」 mean?

Tags: translation, words

I have looked up in an online dictionary and found out that

「いつの間にか」　means before one knows.

For another question, when I have came across 「いつの間に通信」 in an instruction manual, I'm not sure if I can translate it as 'when communication' or 'before communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its official translation, SpotPass, doesn't help understand いつの間に通信. But Wikipedia says its literal translation is [Unnoticed Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpotPass_and_StreetPass).

いつの間に means 'unnoticed', or 'before one notices it's happening'.

> いつの間にか夏が終わってしまった。
>   The summer had gone before I knew / all too soon.

いつの間に in いつの間に通信 implies the connection is done silently, before you are aware it's done, even when your 3DS is closed.